# Is there a way to read when a user changes the cursor position in a UITextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, uitextview

I'm working on an app in which I have to mock a multi-line `textField`, so we're using a `UITextView`.

All of the other functionality is there, except for the "placeholder" text.

For example, in iMessage on iOS, when you tap into the input field, the "iMessage" text goes away and you can write your message.

Since we're mocking placeholder text, a user can move the curser around, even if we prevent them from editing.

Is there a way to have the cursor stay at the beginning of the text, even if the user taps around, or tries to move it by long-pressing the center of the keyboard?

Happy to elaborate or past code if it's helpful.

Comment: Why not intercept the tap?

Comment: @matt , good idea. You mean to put a tap gesture recognizer on it? How could I handle not moving the cursor in the intercept?

Comment: I was thinking of an invisible view that just swallows touches unless you _want_ them to fall thru. I use that sort of masking all the time.

Comment: How would you handle the long press in the center of the keyboard to move the cursor?

Comment: Yeah, that's a problem. I was afraid you'd get to that. :(

Comment: I appreciate your help, thanks a lot!